# I am writing a selenium script and i am not able to write the xpath for the below code

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I am writing a selenium script and i am not able to write the xpath for the below code

```
<div id="notification">
<div class="success">
Success: You have added
 <a href="http://10.207.182.108:81/opencart/index.php?route=product/product&amp;product_id=28">HTC Touch HD</a> to your
 <a href="http://10.207.182.108:81/opencart/index.php?route=checkout/cart">
shopping cart</a>!<img class="close" alt="" src="catalog/view/theme/default/image/close.png"></div></div>
```

I tried the below script and there is success i need to find the text that is appearing within Success notification.

```
//Add 1st Products
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@onclick, '28')]")).click();
    String msg = driver.findElement (By.xpath("//div[@id='notification']/div")).getText();
    String expectedmsg="Success: You have added HTC Touch HD to your shopping cart!";
    Assert.assertEquals(msg, expectedmsg);
```

[THe highlighted one is the xpath i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pTFFC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the xptah:

```
//div[@id='notification']/div[@class='success']
```

Hope that it helps.